# Angular : How to load images through XHR request in ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a contact book in which every person can have a photo.
As I would like to display the contact before getting its photo, I would write something like

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.firstname}} {{persone.lastname}}</li>
</ul>
```

I would try to call a get_photo(person) available in my scope.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.firstname}} {{persone.lastname}}
    <img ng-src="{{get_photo(person)}}" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Which doesn't work because it binds the function to ng-src and call get_photo every time ng-repeat is called.

I finally tried to call get_photo when initializing the DOM element and store the result in a specific attribute photo

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.firstname}} {{persone.lastname}}
    <img ng-init="get_photo(person)" ng-src="{{person.photo}}" />
    </li>
</ul>

$scope.get_photo = function (person) {
    // Simple example; I will try to get an image through xhr request later...
    person.photo = "http://img.blogduwebdesign.com/benjamin-sanchez/737/AngularJS.jpg";
};
```

Is there an easier / cleaner way to do the same ?
I also created a jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/V4Mss/

Thanks a lot for your feedback !

t00f

Comment: You could use `ng-src="{{get_photo(person)}}"` - http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/JTxZS/

Comment: If you do this, you will get extra loop : http://jsfiddle.net/JTxZS/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last example seems fine but here is another option that keeps the view a little cleaner and doesn't cause the double `$digest`. Remove the initialization function from each element and use the function as a getter.

**HTML**

```
<img ng-src="{{person.photo}}" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.get_photo = function (person) {
        return "http://img.blogduwebdesign.com/benjamin-sanchez/737/AngularJS.jpg";
    };
    $scope.persons = [{firstname:"toto", lastname:"TOTO", photo:$scope.get_photo()},
                      {firstname:"tata", lastname:"TATA", photo:$scope.get_photo()},
                      {firstname:"titi", lastname:"TITI", photo:$scope.get_photo()}];

});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/pQ7r7/)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ! I like cleaner methods ;)